# Distinct field Rest Framework Django

Tags: django, api, rest, frameworks, distinct

I need to make a distinct with a field of my model and not how to make

My model is:

```
class CheckList(CoreModel):
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Date'))
establishment = models.ForeignKey(Establishment,  related_name="checklists", on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, verbose_name=_('Establishment'))
user = models.ForeignKey(ITManager, related_name="checklists", on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, verbose_name=_('User'))

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = _("Checklist")
    verbose_name = _("Checklists")

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.date)
```

My serializer and view:

```
class CheckListSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = ITManagerSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = CheckList
    list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
    fields = ['id', 'user', 'establishment', 'date']

class ChecklistBulkViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
queryset = CheckList.objects.values('establishment', 'user', 'date').distinct()
model = CheckList
serializer_class = CheckListSerializer
filter_class = ChecklistFilter
```

The api return me:

```
 "results": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Andres",
    "last_name": "Gallardo",
    "rut": "21312",
    "email": null,
    "user_name": "andres",
    "password": null,
    "user": 4,
    "country": [],
    "active": true
  },
  "establishment": 3,
  "date": "2016-06-14T15:15:00Z"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "user": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Ramiro",
    "last_name": "Gutierrez",
    "rut": "15616+",
    "email": null,
    "user_name": null,
    "password": null,
    "user": 2,
    "country": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Argentina",
        "code_area": null
      }
    ],
    "active": false
  },
  "establishment": 3,
  "date": "2016-06-09T15:40:04Z"
}]
```

I need you just leave me an establishment with the same id

any suggestions??

Thanks !